# django in webfaction & apache memory load

Tags: django, apache, memory-management

I am developing a new application. I am still in development stage. However whenever I restart apache my application gets a **140MB** memory cap. Whereas my other (older and more complex) application gets a **40MB**. This results in webfaction sending me messages about memory usage. Apache by default starts with 2 processes resulting in a more than 300MB memory usage. I changed this to 1 process like this:

```
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess tipleaders processes=1 threads=6 python-path=/home/<<USERNAME>>/webapps/<<WEBSITE>>:/home/<<USERNAME>>/webapps/<<WEBSITE>>/lib/python2.7:/home/<<USERNAME>>/webapps/<<WEBSITE>>/<<WEBSITE>> maximum-requests=10
```

Memory usage does not increase with every request (so I guess it is not a memory leak problem).

It just starts with a very high memory cap (~150MB).

Any ideas what shall I do?

PS: this are my main imports in `views.py` http://dpaste.com/744785/
some other imports are here: http://dpaste.com/744786/
`models.py`, `urls.py` and `settings.py` are here: http://dpaste.com/744787/

EDIT
PS2: My whole site is using SSL

EDIT
as per request, the project is not dealing with media. No images, no videos. It is a simple website which parses 2 xml files with matches (events and results) and displays them to the user. No ads to the site (just one from the affiliator). No big images whatsoever. The site at the dev stage has only 10 users, and the sporting events that have been inserted in the database are not more than 5000.

EDIT:
I installed django-devserver (https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver)

and this is what I get:

```
>python manage.py runserver
    [profile] heap size is 7.9 MB
    [profile] heap size is 7.9 MB

    [sql] (219ms) 2 queries with 0 duplicates
    [profile] Total time to render was 0.14s
    [profile] 5.3 MB allocated, 13.0 KB deallocated, heap size is 13.3 MB
    [sql] (219ms) 2 queries with 0 duplicates
    [profile] Total time to render was 1.08s
    [profile] 404.8 KB allocated, 18.6 KB deallocated, heap size is 13.7 MB
[12/May/2012 12:42:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 146587 (time: 6.93s; sql: 219ms (2q)
```

I am still puzzled on why Apache starts with 140MB allocated for my application.

Comment: Have you tried posting this on http://community.webfaction.com?

Comment: I can do that, too (although I have already contacted the webfaction support team about that and we are investigating on the matter). However I noticed many people come here for similar problems.

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: No. I have read the documentation provided by webfaction and did all that it suggests. What you ask is on the list.

Comment: What is the overall project doing?  Handling images or anything unusual?  This will help others to know if your Django project is standard or not.  (I had problems on Webfaction with huge memory loads when doing image resizing with uploaded images).

Comment: thank you. I edited my question for all the users to know.

Comment: Yes. It was a certain python library that caused the problem. I cannot remember which one was it. But as soon as I removed if from the imports, the problem was resolved. Do you have a similar issue?